# How can I access the AST that LESS generates?

Tags: node.js, less, abstract-syntax-tree

I'd like to perform some code analysis on a LESS stylesheet by accessing the [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). The [programmatic usage](http://lesscss.org/usage/#programmatic-usage) documentation only covers how to render a file or string.

How can I access the [less.js](https://github.com/less/less.js/) AST?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Github user Vecerek had a similar need](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2777). `less.parse` can be used with a callback to access the AST:

> ...I'm putting the actual code here, that works to get the AST, in case someone will be facing the same hurdle and comes across this issue.
>
> ```
> var less = require('less')
>   , fs = require('fs')
>   , path = require('path');
>
> var src = './test_import.less'; //some less source file
> var result = less.parse(fs.readFileSync(src).toString(), {
>   filename: path.resolve(src)
> }, function(e, tree) {
>   console.log(JSON.stringify(tree, null, 2));
> });
> ```

This snippet can be reasonably adapted to use a promise structure, which I find more useful:

```
function lessAST(filename, options) {
    options = options || {};
    options.filename = path.resolve(filename);
    return new Promise(function (res, rej) {
        less.parse(fs.readFileSync(filename).toString(), options, function (e, tree) {
            if (e) {
                rej(e);
            } else {
                res(tree);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Example usage:

```
lessAST('styles.less', {
    ...options...
}).then(function (tree) {
    ...do stuff with the AST...
});
```